# Any way to use Synergy+ and use the mice on *both* computers to travel between screens?

Tags: synergy

I can't seem to figure out how to do it. Seems like only one of the keyboards/mice is able to travel across both screens, while the other one is confined to its own machine.

Any way to make it truly bidirectional?

Answer (score 2):

You could try running both the client and the server on both machines and set them up to use different ports. I've never tested it but it might just work.

Comment: Now I'm all curious if this would work, but I don't have a second mouse laying around to try it...

Answer (score 0):

Linux: Opening two QuickSynergy windows and putting in the hostname/ip in one of the boxes of the Share tab of the first window, and the hostname/ip in the Use tab of the second window is enough for its side of a two-way connection.

Windows: The standard Synergy GUI window (`synergy.exe`) kills off the existing server (`synergys.exe`) or client (`synergyc.exe`) to start a new one even if you use two windows (the log shows whatever's currently running), so won't normally work for creating a two-way connection, unless you know how to keep one process from killing another.

Instead, first start a server through the window (because it has more options to set up), then run, with the proper hostname/ip,

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Synergy\synergyc.exe' --restart 192.168.1.123
```

Caveats: If you have recently changed your Windows hostname, it will be different between a client spawned by the Synergy window compared to a client spawned by command line. The remote server's screen edge rules must be updated to reflect this. `--relaunch` is in the `--help` menu, but not recognized. I assume it was replaced by `--restart`. When attempting to cross the border to the remote screen, the pointer may loop back to the opposite local edge, or inherit being invisible depending on whether the remote mouse is on its home screen. When on the same screen, the local mouse will move the pointer from where it is, but the remote mouse will move the pointer from where it last left it.